# Material floating label text field dimensions don't add up to 72dp

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Having problems with the spacing in textinputlayout and looking at the official design guide, the numbers don't add up to 72.

16 + 12 + 8+ 16+16 = 68???

[image]

[image]
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels

Answer (score 0):

sp and dp are different units. 1sp is not equal to 1dp. That is why the numbers don't add up to 72